# Magento 1.8 Shopping Cart Price Rule Actions Reloading Back to Admin Mainscreen

Tags: magento-1.8, shopping-cart-price-rules, ce-1.8.1.0

Magento 1.8.1.0 site, I can setup a coupon code in Shopping Cart Price Rule, however if I click on Actions and try to add a rule under, 
Apply the rule only to cart items matching the following conditions (leave blank for all items)

No matter what I choose, it says please wait, loading and then it redirects back to the admin dashboard

There is nothing in the apache error log, nothing in /var/logs or /var/reports

Looking at the headers, the post seems to be returning a 403 forbidden causing the redirect back to the admin dashboard.

POST /shop/index.php/admin/promo_quote/newActionHtml/form/rule_actions_fieldset/key/1cae7594b03c160b9bca92d514c7942b/?isAjax=true HTTP/1.1

Response 403 Forbidden

Looking for a way to debug this.

Comment: Did you solve the issue?

Comment: Anyone solve this issue?

Comment: Never found a solution, still happening. We have just been working around it by reusing old coupons.